# GatherBy[list, f] except with sublists ordered by f's value

Tags: gathering

I want something like `GatherBy[list, OddQ]` but it either consistently puts the odd elements first or consistently puts the even elements first, rather than have it depend on `list`. The actual function I want to use it with is also boolean, although a more general solution that doesn't rely on this would be nice to have as well.

Comment: `KeySortBy[OddQ]@GatherBy[list, OddQ]`

Comment: @b3m2a1, you meant `GroupBy` i think.

Comment: @kglr oh I totally did. Missed the fact that the question was about `GatherBy`. Same approach will work with more post-processing or a different `SortBy` strategy

Comment: Could you please provide some examples to enrich the point you want to express?

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomSample@Range[10]
manyLists = Table[RandomSample@list, 10]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 7 & 2 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 10 & 4 & 6 & 5 \\
 3 & 6 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 10 & 1 \\
 7 & 6 & 8 & 3 & 2 & 10 & 9 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
 3 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 10 & 5 & 4 & 9 \\
 9 & 5 & 8 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 1 & 4 & 7 \\
 6 & 10 & 2 & 9 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 7 \\
 4 & 10 & 6 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 5 \\
 1 & 10 & 8 & 9 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 9 & 10 & 2 \\
 6 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 9 & 3 & 2 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

```
Last@
   Reap[
    Scan[
     If [EvenQ[#],
       Sow[#, even],
       Sow[#, odd]
       ] &, #]] & /@ manyLists
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{7,9,1,3,5\} & \{2,8,10,4,6\} \\
 \{3,9,5,7,1\} & \{6,4,2,8,10\} \\
 \{7,3,9,5,1\} & \{6,8,2,10,4\} \\
 \{3,7,1,5,9\} & \{2,8,6,10,4\} \\
 \{9,5,3,1,7\} & \{8,2,6,10,4\} \\
 \{6,10,2,8,4\} & \{9,1,3,5,7\} \\
 \{4,10,6,8,2\} & \{1,7,9,3,5\} \\
 \{1,9,3,5,7\} & \{10,8,4,2,6\} \\
 \{3,5,1,7,9\} & \{4,8,6,10,2\} \\
 \{6,8,4,2,10\} & \{7,5,1,9,3\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

Reaping {even,odd} will fix how the sublists are presented.

```
Last@
   Reap[
    Scan[
     If [EvenQ[#],
       Sow[#, even],
       Sow[#, odd]
       ] &, #], {even, odd}] & /@ manyLists
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to preserve the relative ordering of elements in each group, you can do:

```
ClearAll[sortedGatherBy]
sortedGatherBy = SortBy[#2 @* First] @ GatherBy[#, #2] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomSample@Range[10]
```

> ```
> {2, 5, 1, 10, 8, 6, 7, 9, 3, 4}
> ```

```
Table[sortedGatherBy[RandomSample @ list, OddQ], 10]
```

[image]

```
Table[sortedGatherBy[RandomSample @ list, Between[{3, 6}]], 10] // Grid
```

[image]

```
Table[sortedGatherBy[RandomSample @ list, Mod[#, 3] &], 10] // Grid
```

[image]

If it is ok to have the elements in each group sorted, then you can do

```
ClearAll[sortedGatherBy2]
sortedGatherBy2 = GatherBy[SortBy[#2]@#, #2] &;

Table[sortedGatherBy2[RandomSample @ list, OddQ], 10] // Grid
```

[image]